# How to get pynotify to display line breaks and HTML?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pynotify

How can I make pynotify display line breaks and HTML in the notifications?

Here is what I got:

```
>>> import pynotify
>>> n = pynotify.Notification ("This is a test.\n\nAnd this too!",
                               "","notification-message-im")
>>> n.show()
```

Contrary to what is expected, there is no line-break between the two sentences. (At least not on Ubuntu 10.04)

Also, is there a way to include simple HTML in the notifications, like `<b>`, `<br>`, or `<i>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use '\n' in message body but not in summary.

```
>>> n = pynotify.Notification("summary", "body\n next line", "dialog-warning")
>>> n.show()
```